# I have a particular coding style, does it have a name?

Tags: coding-style

I don't know if it is just what my first Java lecturer taught me or if it is based on something. It has parts of it that are the same as the Oracle Java style (naming) but differs in other ways, as they seems to prefer K&R braces.

1. Braces are always on a line of their own.
2. Even one line statements inside blocks get braces.
3. Spaces after the comma separating parameters.
4. Spaces between the operator and the variables for binary operators but not for unary operators.
5. Four spaces for a tab.
6. Blank lines between separate concepts inside functions and between class level elements i.e. separating functions from each other and from declarations/definitions.
7. Capital for each new word.
8. Classes start with a capital.
9. Functions and variables start with a lower case letter.
10. Constants are all capitals.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static final float PI = 3.14;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        if((1 + 2) == 3 && returnFirstMinusSecond(9, 2) == 7 && !returnsFalse())
        {
            // output 
            System.out.println("true");

            // some other code that is logically separate from output
            // do something else that I want to keep separate as it is complex
        }
        else
        {
            while(true)
            {
                System.out.println("false");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Standard Java"? I mean, what am I missing?

Comment: Seems to be [Allman Style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#Allman_style) for indent+braces. It's certainly not K&R.

Comment: BTW: Consider using a java highlighting hint or the java tag...

Comment: I might call your No.2 rule of explicitly putting braces even for one line statements "Perl style" because Perl enforces this rule in the language. Your rules about adding spaces after commas seem like the same rule that is used in standard English prose. e.g. "I think, therefore I am."

Comment: Your No.5 rule is known in some text editors as "Insert spaces for tabs" or "expandtab" in VIM.

Comment: This is pretty much the exact style I like, the only problem is I'm in C++ and it seems unusual amongst C++ programmers to use #1.

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6582/on-the-troubles-of-naming-and-terminology

Comment: Yes, it has a name: Weird. Just like all the other coding conventions ;-)

Comment: @gnat The link you post with no explanation has the top answer saying that naming things is on topic unless it is off topic for some other reason. I wanted a name for it so I could google for it. I showed my working by giving examples of close by not quite right names and asked for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Coding styles generally aren't referred to by name unless the name is a clear reference to a *published style guide,* such as the [ones published by Google.](https://code.google.com/p/google-styleguide/)

Indeed, rarely is the collective styles of indentation, naming convention, alignment, etc. given a single name, and even those individual styles don't have standard names.

Based on your description, however, I can give you the names that are commonly-accepted by parts of the programming community:

- Your **indentation style** is usually called [**Allman Style**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#Allman_style), for Eric Allman, the author of sendmail and syslog.
- Your **naming convention** is generally referred to as [**CamelCase**](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?CamelCase), in reference to the bumpy use of upper- and lower-case letters. More specifically, you are mixing **UpperCamelCase** (also sometimes called PascalCase) for class names and **lowerCamelCase** for method names.

Other than that, there isn't really an applicable name for operator style or alignment of which I am aware.

Your use of internal whitespace (such as between operators and in parameter lists and between logical blocks), however, is widely regarded as simply "good style."

Comment: +1 Exactly what I was going to write. I'd add that in OP's list items 2, 3, 4 and 6 would probably be considered "good coding style" and also not given any specific name.

Comment: @greyfade Thanks. I had misread the wiki page on Allman. Allman + CamelCase + Good is as close as seems to be possible.